# Is it possible to prevent application from hanging when both stdin and stdout are connected to named pipes?

Tags: c, linux, bash, pipe, named-pipes

Consider the following simple C program, which I will compile to a program called "A":

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  putchar('C');
  putchar('\n');
}
```

Now, consider the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkfifo Output1.pipe
mkfifo Output2.pipe

stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 ./A > Output1.pipe  &
stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 ./A > Output2.pipe  &

cat Output1.pipe
cat Output2.pipe
```

The output of this script is `C\nC`. So far everything is fine.
Now let's consider the following modification the bash script, observing that the C program never reads `stdin`.

```
#!/bin/bash

mkfifo Input1.pipe
mkfifo Input2.pipe

mkfifo Output1.pipe
mkfifo Output2.pipe

stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 ./A > Output1.pipe < Input1.pipe &
stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 ./A > Output2.pipe < Input2.pipe &

cat Output1.pipe
cat Output2.pipe
```

When this bash script is run, it hangs until output is manually written to Input1.pipe and then Input2.pipe.

What is going on here and is there a way to get it to not hang at this step?

Comment: Say you wanted to `prog1` to send data to `prog2` via a named pipe. Let's say opening the pipe was allowed to succeed without blocking. If you launched `prog1` first, writing would fail (and probably send a SIGPIPE to `prog1`), so you'd lose data or your program would die. If you launched `prog2` first, if would get an error or EOF, so it would think there's no input coming.

Comment: One of them must therefore wait, and it was deemed to be the reader. Opening a named pipe for reading blocks until a writer connects. So the question is: Is there a ways to check or be notified when a writer connects to a named pipe? I don't know the answer.

Comment: These points make a lot of sense. I think my original mental model is that the reader would block *only when it tried to read* rather than when opening the pipe, which is why the observed behavior surprised me.

Answer (score 0):

In this setup, your program doesn't even run (AFAIR), because the shell first opens both channels and then the program is started. And opening a reading FIFO hangs until it is opened writing as well.

There is no (easy) way to prevent this.

Comment: Is there some trick I can use to open the other end for writing and then actually write to it *after* reading?