# Is it possible for bash to "interactively" alternate between reading from and writing to a child process via stdin/stdout?

Tags: bash, stdout, stdin

This question has been asked for many languages but I have yet to find the bash-flavored duplicate.

Suppose I have a program that alternates between writing `stdout` and reading `stdin`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*
 * Control_D to exit.
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv){
  char init = 'C';
  if (argc > 1) {
    init = *argv[1];
  }
  putchar(init);
  putchar('\n');

  while (1) {
    int c = getchar();
    if (c == -1) {
      return 0;
    }
    putchar(c);
    putchar('\n');
  }
}
```

I would like to write a bash script that reads what the program wrote and then decides what to write standard input, and does this repeatedly. That is, something like this:

```
myProgram &

for i in $(seq 1 10);
do
output=$(# magic command to read myProgram stdout)
if [[ $output = "C" ]]; then
# Magic command to write 'C' to myProgram input
fi
if [[ $output = "D" ]]; then
# Magic command to write 'E' to myProgram input
done
```

I initially tried to do this with [named pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61767692/391161) but this did not work because pipes require both ends to be open before starting and using various `exec` tricks did not manage to workaround these limitations. I am not ruling them out as a solution, merely pointing out that I was not sufficiently clever to get them to work.

**Do these magic commands exist in bash, or do I have to switch to another language?**

Let's assume for the sake of this question that I have no control over `myProgram` and cannot dictate how it communicates; it only understands stdin and stdout because it was intended to be used interactively by a user.

Comment: Named pipes work fine when you flush stdout after putchar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [`coproc` builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Coprocesses.html). It allows you run commands asynchronously and provides you file descriptors to interact with i.e. a pair of fd's, connected to both stdin and stdout of the command

```
coproc myProgram
```

The built-in returns the fd pair in the array named `COPROC` if no name is provided by default. You need something like

To write to the program

```
printf 'foo' >&${COPROC[1]}
```

To read from the program

```
read -u "${COPROC[0]}" var
```

So your whole program would look like below. Assuming `myprogram` is the executable available in the current path.

```
coproc ./myProgram 

for ((i=1; i<=10; i++)); do
    read -u "${COPROC[0]}" var
    if [[ $var = "C" ]]; then
        printf 'C' >&${COPROC[1]}
    elif [[ $var = "D" ]]; then
        printf 'E' >&${COPROC[1]}
    fi
done
```

Like running a background job using `&` provides the process id in `$!` running the program using `coproc` automatically updates the process id in `COPROC_PID` variable, so that you can do below, when you are done with the program

```
kill "$COPROC_PID"
```

---

Untested, but I think you might need to flush out stdout as its not line buffered by default. Use `fflush(stdout)` from your C program or run the executable with `stdbuf -oL`

Answer (score 1):

And alternatively to `coproc` you can just use a fifo. Either two fifos, one for input and one for output, or a fifo and a file descriptor with a redirection. Below I use bash extension `>(...)` process substitution with a file descriptor and a fifo:

```
f=/tmp/fifo.fifo
mkfifo "$f"
exec 10> >( { echo "Header!"; sed 's/^/process: /'; } >"$f" )

IFS= read -r first_line <"$f"
echo "First line: $first_line"
# "First line: Header!"

echo 123 >&10
IFS= read -r second_line <"$f"
echo "Second line: $second_line"
# Second line: process: 123

exec 10<&-
rm "$f"
```

So your program can look like:

```
f=/tmp/fifo.fifo
mkfifo "$f"
exec 10> >(myProgram >"$f")

for i in $(seq 1 10); do
    IFS= read -r output <"$f"
    if [[ $output = "C" ]]; then
          echo "C" >&10
    fi
    if [[ $output = "D" ]]; then
         echo "D" >&10
    fi
done

exec 10<&-
rm "$f"
```

Comment: As written, when I copied and pasted the first block of code, script blocked forever after outputting `First line: Header!`

Comment: Second example did not appear to work, but I probably translated it wrong into my context.